# Why does the tooltip show up on the wrong point in Plotly.js scatter plot?

Tags: javascript, charts, tooltip, scatter-plot, plotly.js

I posted this question over at the Plotly community here: https://community.plotly.com/t/why-does-the-tooltip-show-on-the-wrong-point-in-scatter-plot/78835. I'm posting it again here to get more responses.

I have a scatter plot. When I hover over the points, the tooltips that show the values show up on the wrong point:

[image]

Is this a bug in Plotly? Is there any way to fix it?

Thank you.

EDIT:

GetSet asked for me to post the data and the layout:

Data:

```
[
   {
      "type":"scatter",
      "mode":"markers",
      "x":[
         11.296296296296296,
         9.444444444444445,
         9.814814814814815,
         9.351851851851851,
         10.87962962962963,
         14.23611111111111,
         13.935185185185185,
         11.73611111111111,
         12.731481481481481,
         16.13425925925926,
         13.518518518518519,
         12.222222222222221,
         12.430555555555555,
         10.532407407407407,
         11.50462962962963,
         8.88888888888889,
         9.328703703703704,
         12.939814814814815,
         14.027777777777779,
         14.699074074074074,
         15.023148148148149,
         16.38888888888889,
         14.976851851851851,
         11.875,
         14.560185185185185,
         16.15740740740741,
         14.837962962962964,
         15.833333333333334,
         15.856481481481481,
         13.981481481481481,
         15.694444444444445,
         16.89814814814815,
         18.14814814814815,
         17.314814814814813,
         15.4,
         14.305555555555555,
         14.907407407407407,
         12.61574074074074,
         12.268518518518519,
         9.027777777777779,
         8.356481481481481,
         9.907407407407407,
         13.00925925925926,
         13.449074074074074,
         12.222222222222221,
         10.50925925925926,
         8.796296296296296,
         8.541666666666666,
         8.287037037037036,
         5.185185185185185,
         11.13425925925926,
         10.833333333333334,
         10.833333333333334,
         8.703703703703704,
         3.7731481481481484,
         5.092592592592593,
         6.736111111111111,
         6.944444444444445,
         8.26388888888889,
         8.86574074074074,
         9.027777777777779,
         6.296296296296297,
         7.060185185185185,
         8.425925925925926,
         6.736111111111111,
         6.018518518518518,
         5.601851851851852,
         3.125,
         1.875,
         1.2037037037037037,
         2.5231481481481484,
         5.138888888888889,
         4.305555555555555,
         2.638888888888889,
         -0.23148148148148148,
         -1.3425925925925926,
         0.20833333333333334,
         -2.5462962962962963,
         -3.5416666666666665,
         -2.986111111111111,
         -4.375,
         -1.5046296296296295,
         -4.537037037037037,
         -3.7962962962962963,
         8.564814814814815,
         10.694444444444445,
         8.587962962962964,
         9.398148148148149,
         10.856481481481481,
         10,
         9.25925925925926,
         7.662037037037037,
         5.486111111111111,
         9.027777777777779,
         9.62962962962963,
         8.75,
         15.917874396135266,
         13.00925925925926,
         9.88425925925926,
         6.712962962962963,
         11.319444444444445,
         11.064814814814815,
         10.972222222222221,
         10.416666666666666,
         8.333333333333334,
         6.782407407407407,
         6.273148148148148,
         10.416666666666666,
         9.907407407407407,
         8.703703703703704,
         8.935185185185185,
         6.50462962962963,
         4.606481481481482,
         0.7870370370370371,
         0.39351851851851855,
         1.3657407407407407,
         0.5092592592592593,
         -1.7824074074074074,
         -0.7870370370370371,
         1.5509259259259258,
         1.9675925925925926,
         -1.3425925925925926,
         2.060185185185185,
         3.8425925925925926,
         1.4351851851851851,
         0.16203703703703703,
         6.25,
         5.324074074074074,
         7.037037037037037,
         8.518518518518519,
         9.398148148148149,
         7.569444444444445,
         6.273148148148148,
         3.1712962962962963,
         1.2731481481481481,
         0.9027777777777778,
         1.5942028985507246,
         4.62962962962963,
         6.898148148148148,
         6.833333333333333,
         5.579710144927536,
         6.416666666666667,
         5.99537037037037,
         7.939814814814815,
         11.712962962962964,
         10.277777777777779,
         8.726851851851851,
         7.106481481481482,
         6.157407407407407,
         6.736111111111111,
         7.75462962962963,
         4.513888888888889,
         3.564814814814815,
         0.9953703703703703,
         1.0185185185185186,
         0.9490740740740741,
         1.5509259259259258,
         2.9166666666666665,
         2.013888888888889,
         5.5092592592592595,
         3.888888888888889,
         3.888888888888889,
         3.1481481481481484,
         1.25,
         6.1342592592592595,
         6.481481481481482,
         2.8472222222222223,
         8.171296296296296,
         13.703703703703704,
         6.62037037037037,
         4.74537037037037,
         8.981481481481481,
         12.476851851851851,
         12.152777777777779,
         10.462962962962964,
         8.356481481481481,
         11.435185185185185,
         11.435185185185185,
         12.662037037037036,
         11.273148148148149,
         9.953703703703704,
         7.318840579710145,
         4.675925925925926,
         4.282407407407407,
         11.435185185185185,
         13.61111111111111,
         11.157407407407407,
         9.027777777777779,
         5.833333333333333,
         4.8842592592592595,
         4.861111111111111,
         6.342592592592593,
         6.111111111111111,
         8.449074074074074,
         9.88425925925926,
         10.578703703703704,
         11.11111111111111,
         10.231481481481481,
         8.564814814814815,
         9.00462962962963,
         8.796296296296296,
         10.162037037037036,
         8.26388888888889,
         10.300925925925926,
         9.814814814814815,
         11.875,
         7.569444444444445,
         10.532407407407407,
         10.393518518518519,
         11.087962962962964,
         9.050925925925926,
         7.152777777777778,
         6.296296296296297,
         9.12037037037037,
         12.685185185185185,
         10.949074074074074,
         12.87037037037037,
         13.726851851851851,
         11.018518518518519,
         10.48611111111111,
         16.666666666666668,
         14.976851851851851,
         14.930555555555555,
         15.671296296296296,
         16.22685185185185,
         13.333333333333334,
         12.893518518518519,
         13.333333333333334,
         14.23611111111111,
         16.412037037037038,
         14.953703703703704,
         11.064814814814815,
         10.462962962962964,
         10.856481481481481,
         10.76388888888889,
         13.449074074074074,
         15.625,
         17.037037037037038,
         15.37037037037037,
         13.541666666666666,
         11.481481481481481,
         13.333333333333334,
         13.472222222222221,
         15.578703703703704,
         17.569444444444443,
         14.74537037037037,
         14.351851851851851,
         18.078703703703702,
         15.37037037037037,
         13.796296296296296,
         17.15277777777778,
         17.824074074074073,
         17.77777777777778,
         18.40277777777778,
         17.77777777777778,
         20.74074074074074,
         23.24074074074074,
         25.53240740740741,
         25.76388888888889,
         24.537037037037038,
         23.10185185185185,
         21.50462962962963,
         21.52777777777778,
         21.550925925925927,
         22.24537037037037,
         21.319444444444443,
         21.89814814814815,
         22.26851851851852,
         21.78240740740741,
         18.21759259259259,
         21.01851851851852,
         22.26851851851852,
         24.814814814814813,
         20.416666666666668,
         18.72685185185185,
         19.189814814814813,
         19.60648148148148,
         18.171296296296298,
         17.685185185185187,
         18.194444444444443,
         17.5,
         17.98611111111111,
         16.064814814814813,
         17.40740740740741,
         21.62037037037037,
         25.439814814814813,
         23.49537037037037,
         21.75925925925926,
         23.24074074074074,
         19.12037037037037,
         18.078703703703702,
         20.949074074074073,
         21.921296296296298,
         18.333333333333332,
         17.962962962962962,
         18.51851851851852,
         18.287037037037038,
         17.662037037037038,
         15.76388888888889,
         17.24537037037037,
         18.26388888888889,
         17.199074074074073,
         15.532407407407407,
         17.662037037037038,
         16.875,
         20.09259259259259,
         19.76851851851852,
         17.36111111111111,
         17.40740740740741,
         17.12962962962963,
         17.89351851851852,
         16.38888888888889,
         16.319444444444443,
         14.86111111111111,
         13.518518518518519,
         15.439814814814815,
         15.277777777777779,
         16.96759259259259,
         17.77777777777778,
         21.550925925925927,
         20.23148148148148,
         19.328703703703702,
         20.833333333333332,
         21.34259259259259,
         20.208333333333332,
         18.75,
         21.34259259259259,
         23.125,
         22.01388888888889,
         21.25,
         20,
         20.925925925925927,
         20.162037037037038,
         18.77314814814815,
         16.50462962962963,
         15.439814814814815,
         15.25462962962963,
         15.11574074074074,
         14.23611111111111,
         14.930555555555555,
         17.430555555555557,
         18.935185185185187,
         18.796296296296298,
         19.23611111111111,
         22.40740740740741,
         22.800925925925927,
         22.916666666666668,
         23.21759259259259,
         23.49537037037037,
         24.88425925925926,
         22.38425925925926,
         20.37037037037037,
         17.685185185185187,
         16.15740740740741,
         16.99074074074074,
         18.958333333333332,
         20.27777777777778,
         19.583333333333332,
         16.89814814814815,
         18.75,
         16.85185185185185,
         13.402777777777779,
         13.171296296296296,
         13.425925925925926,
         15.347222222222221
      ],
      "y":[
         92,
         267,
         277,
         300,
         291,
         139,
         104,
         266,
         275,
         287,
         278,
         316,
         173,
         133,
         238,
         275,
         277,
         277,
         183,
         139,
         143,
         274,
         278,
         277,
         268,
         279,
         204,
         174,
         287,
         281,
         281,
         289,
         293,
         198,
         146,
         138,
         139,
         300,
         279,
         288,
         220,
         205,
         175,
         285,
         210,
         178,
         165,
         167,
         173,
         262,
         175,
         164,
         266,
         310,
         229,
         208,
         300,
         288,
         290,
         300,
         296,
         228,
         224,
         302,
         305,
         282,
         286,
         293,
         230,
         217,
         305,
         283,
         285,
         275,
         250,
         185,
         191,
         296,
         283,
         274,
         261,
         209,
         222,
         225,
         257,
         235,
         304,
         278,
         257,
         200,
         201,
         199,
         213,
         220,
         219,
         219,
         213,
         198,
         192,
         328,
         315,
         279,
         250,
         210,
         218,
         285,
         274,
         272,
         283,
         294,
         219,
         214,
         235,
         258,
         287,
         252,
         263,
         141,
         102,
         264,
         265,
         273,
         271,
         273,
         143,
         113,
         286,
         296,
         275,
         254,
         260,
         142,
         108,
         265,
         268,
         271,
         280,
         193,
         95,
         94,
         248,
         258,
         270,
         273,
         267,
         122,
         90,
         266,
         270,
         264,
         263,
         270,
         125,
         104,
         282,
         297,
         290,
         291,
         285,
         142,
         106,
         95,
         81,
         83,
         75,
         216,
         132,
         98,
         273,
         293,
         276,
         303,
         271,
         122,
         89,
         268,
         259,
         266,
         274,
         273,
         127,
         92,
         257,
         263,
         246,
         263,
         273,
         131,
         110,
         301,
         265,
         264,
         256,
         126,
         92,
         89,
         90,
         267,
         256,
         274,
         260,
         127,
         95,
         268,
         255,
         284,
         274,
         187,
         102,
         96,
         239,
         235,
         242,
         245,
         256,
         144,
         106,
         102,
         257,
         253,
         255,
         253,
         127,
         92,
         245,
         241,
         258,
         262,
         259,
         124,
         93,
         238,
         264,
         261,
         128,
         97,
         89,
         86,
         227,
         266,
         293,
         248,
         122,
         88,
         93,
         96,
         244,
         232,
         248,
         93,
         92,
         93,
         252,
         263,
         275,
         261,
         137,
         85,
         88,
         275,
         255,
         248,
         255,
         222,
         83,
         85,
         227,
         248,
         246,
         254,
         211,
         85,
         87,
         247,
         281,
         275,
         246,
         120,
         92,
         96,
         272,
         238,
         234,
         263,
         256,
         120,
         81,
         90,
         255,
         250,
         263,
         273,
         119,
         96,
         253,
         237,
         257,
         216,
         147,
         91,
         92,
         254,
         252,
         257,
         126,
         90,
         95,
         97,
         267,
         260,
         238,
         244,
         279,
         125,
         87,
         102,
         89,
         90,
         84,
         80,
         77,
         77,
         77,
         81,
         234,
         263,
         259,
         86,
         82,
         274,
         265,
         254,
         231,
         259,
         116,
         92,
         89,
         248,
         262,
         246,
         269,
         139,
         119,
         260,
         270,
         268,
         242,
         111,
         113,
         111,
         261,
         244,
         232,
         214,
         275,
         144,
         120,
         245,
         253,
         246,
         238,
         256,
         181,
         180,
         293
      ],
      "name":"°C",
      "marker":{
         "color":[
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#89d300",
            "#4d9700",
            "#4d9700",
            "#89d300"
         ],
         "size":3,
         "opacity":1
      }
   }
]
```

Layout:

```
{
   "title":{
      "text":"Scatter Plot",
      "font":{
         "color":"#3dcd58",
         "family":"Nunito-Regular",
         "size":18
      },
      "xanchor":"left",
      "x":0
   },
   "font":{
      "color":"#333",
      "family":"Nunito-Regular"
   },
   "dragmode":"lasso",
   "autosize":false,
   "width":425,
   "height":400,
   "margin":{
      "l":20,
      "r":15,
      "b":30,
      "t":30
   },
   "plot_bgcolor":"#ffffff",
   "showlegend":false,
   "yaxis":{
      "title":"kWh",
      "showticklabels":false,
      "range":[
         62.35,
         340.65
      ]
   },
   "xaxis":{
      "title":"°C",
      "titlefont":{
         "color":"#89d300"
      },
      "showticklabels":false,
      "side":"bottom",
      "range":[
         -6.052083333333334,
         27.278935185185187
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Any code to share? I get it, which parts would be relevant. Could you post the setup/config code for the graph you show? Code that configures the options

Comment: Hi GetSet, I posted the data and the layout. Hopefully you can see something.

Comment: Seems to be a long standing bug, see here on their forums https://community.plotly.com/t/tool-tip-on-wrong-dot-in-scattergl/14470 . I'll take a look at their api source for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug, this is the expected behavior when having `"hovermode": "x"` in the layout config, where you would need to have `"hovermode": "closest"` instead.

Note that having `"hovermode": "x"` as default suggests you are using an outdated version of Plotly.js, the default hovermode is set to "closest" since Plotly.js-2.0.0 ([changelog](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#changed-19)).

The main reason people use an outdated (< 2.0.0) version is because they refer to "plotly-latest" as source file, thinking it's the latest obviously while it's not :

> As of v2 the "plotly-latest" outputs (e.g.
> `https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js`) will no longer be updated on
> the CDN, and will stay at the last v1 patch v1.58.5. Therefore, to use
> the CDN with plotly.js v2 and higher, you must specify an exact
> plotly.js version.

Comment: Thanks both for your stellar advice. Setting hovermode to 'closest' is exactly what I needed. And thanks Eric for pointing out the version I'm on.